# How can I minimize my iOS application using button?

Tags: ios

How can I minimize my iOS application using a button? I'm using Xcode and Swift 3.

Comment: Just press Home button? Not sure what you're asking.

Comment: I think I had said, "using button".

Comment: I think if you're expecting a better answer, you should probably improve your question. Your question doesn't show any research effort. Could you please at least show what you tried so far ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Inside the `IBAction` of your button add this

```
UIControl().sendAction(#selector(URLSessionTask.suspend), to: UIApplication.shared, for: nil)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, (mucho gracias)

Comment: Thank you very much. I've been looking for this for a long time.

Answer (score 5):

**This action is not recommended by Apple to be done programmatically.**

This process is intended to be done with the single press of the Home button.

It is up to the user to close/minimize the app if needed.

Comment: is there any documentation related to this.

Comment: What about TVos?

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this. It is not recommended and your app will be rejected.

[Apple developer question](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1561/_index.html)

Comment: OK. In fact there is no button, but it's the same, 
I'm using User Local notification action, and when user receive a notification, there is 2 choices, NO or YES. 
I want to ignore the notification in the case of selecting NO and rest outside of app, and if select YES, then go into app.

Comment: Dismiss the alert when push NO and go into app when YES selected.